# Automated build tools for .NET, VC 6.0 and VB 6.0

Tags: .net, build

I wonder if there is any build/continuouse integration tool for building  .NET, VC 6.0, and VB 6.0 projects. I read a little bit about [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/), but it seems doesn't support VisualBasic 6.0 stuff.
Do you know some others?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you set up CruiseControl to run custom commands? If so, I think all you should need to do is to call it like `[pathToExe]\VB6.ex /MAKE [yourprojectfile.vbp]`.

Though be aware that if you have WebClass designers in your VB6 project there's a known bug with compiling it like that as can be seen [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190165).